# How to follow the entire wiki in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-wiki

Right now User can subscribe to the wiki by Page. There are around 100 pages in wiki and new pages also get created very frequently. So Is there any way to get a notification if there is any change in the wiki?

I have followed [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/6591) bug, It's mentioned that it's not supported yet officially.

So If anyone has the latest update on this or if there is any workaround to subscribe to the entire wiki, please update.

If there are APIs to get the required information that will also solve the purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wiki is a git repo. So you can subscribe on git changes.

Wiki:

[image]

Notification:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: How to open this subscription page?

Comment: @viveknuna, you can use [team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/manage-team-group-global-organization-notifications?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-account-enabled) or [personal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/manage-your-personal-notifications?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-account-enabled) notifications

Comment: are you sure it works for wiki as well

Comment: @viveknuna, my screenshots from my wiki.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! Do you know of a way to handle all updates to code wikis (so not project wikis, as described here) as well please?

Comment: @ShamraiAleksander Has this changed? My wiki isn't listed under "A specific team Project"

Comment: @cyclingLinguist type it manually. By default: project name + ".wiki". Additionally, you may use the `contains` rule.